# pass array values from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
<script>
$("#submit").click(function () {
   var newhour= [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i++) {
        newhour.push(arrayNumbers[i].toString().split(','));   
        console.log("each: " + newhour[i]); // output: each: 07:00,08:30
                                                       each: 18:00,19:00                                                   
   }
   console.log("all: " + newhour); //output: all: 07:00,08:30,18:00,19:00

   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(newhour);
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "exp.php",
         data:{data: jsonString}, 
         cache: false,
         success: function(){
                  alert("OK");
         }
   });
});
<script>
```

I want to pass the newhour array values to php and use them to insert into a table.
so php file, exp.php:

```
$data = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
foreach($data as $d){
  echo $d;
  $sql = "insert into exp_table (hour) values ('$d')";
  mysql_query($sql);
}
```

However I can not take the values. What is wrong with the code?
Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

according to the answers i tried this on php side, but it returns NULL.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
//$data = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
echo "data: " .$data;
var_dump($data); // no output
foreach($data as $d){
  echo $d; // no output
}
```

Comment: to convert `JSON` in php to array use `json_decode` not explode.

Comment: Is the $_POST variable empty ? Do you get a hit on your exp.php file ? Do you have javascript error ?

Comment: when I tried to get data with echo $data, it gives me that it is array. It is not give the values @Thibault

Comment: Yes, explode() returns an Array. To display the content, use var_dump() or print_r()

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Thibault, it returns NULL with var_dump($data);

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array without `JSON.stringify` in ajax data post. And fetch the data in php file using `$_POST['data']`.

I just have tried below code and it working great.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  print_r($_POST);exit;
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var newhour= [];
   arrayNumbers = [['07:00','08:30'],['08:30','18:00','19:00']];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i++) {
        newhour.push(arrayNumbers[i].toString().split(','));   
        console.log("each: " + newhour[i]); 
        // output: each: 07:00,08:30 each: 18:00,19:00                                                   
   }
   console.log("all: " + newhour); //output: all: 07:00,08:30,18:00,19:00

   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "abc.php",
         data:{data: newhour}, 
         cache: false,
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
         }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh yes, inserting `$_REQUEST` data into the database blindly seems like such a good idea...

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Dude, really, I gotta ask, are you parsing new questions and automatically posting that answer? Not complaining or anything, the sooner `mysql_*` dies the better.

Comment: @Andrew No, :)  I just have a set of comments sitting in an editor waiting to go.

Comment: @Ozzlem When you print_r($_POST) on the top of the PHP file what are you getting?

Comment: Pass the array from ajax without JSON.stringify and you will able to get the values by using $_POST itself no need to json_decode.

Comment: @RahulPatel , I did exactly what you suggest but still no data. Also I print_r($_POST) on the top of php code, it does not give the any array value.

Comment: @Ozzlem can you please assign the newhour array like var newhour= {}; and try again.

Comment: @RahulPatel when I did this, it can not run my functions as newhour.push,  it says it is not a function

Comment: @Ozzlem Can you please check my answer now. Do you trying exactly same as my code? Please compare your arrayNumbers array as well. Because I have tried the exact code here and it is working great.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to stringify an array in the javascript.

.ajax looks after all that.

pass

```
data: {newhours: newhour},
```

then you will get `$_POST['newhours']` in the PHP code which will be the array you had in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax there is not "type" params, use "method". 
Beside that everything should works, you might need to decode the json using `json_decode($_POST['data'])` on in your php file.
Hopes it helps !

- Nic

Comment: `json_decode($var, true)` for array output. No `true` for `stdClass`. Directed towards OP.

Comment: @Andrew Yea you're right, but in the end it gives the same results.

Comment: Absolutely, it wasn't criticism, I just figured OP may look over your answer and some people prefer working with arrays. It's nice to have that option too. No harm intended.

Comment: "type" exists : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -> type (default: 'GET') An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: @Thibault My bad, I never used type before.Both works i guess.

Comment: @Nicolas I learned it today too ;-) That's why I checked the doc :-)